# How to test if a distribution is exponential in Stata?

Tags: distributions, stata

Well, to figure out a distribution we need to do a histogram. We can also do a quantile normal plot. Is there some specific test/graph plotting (in Stata) that will help determine if a distribution is exponential or not?

To be more specific, I am looking for something like normal quantile plot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Stata, there is a user-written module, called [dpplot](http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s426201.html), that allows you to do density probability plots. You can install the module via the following command

```
ssc install dpplot
```

There is an [article in Stata Journal](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=gr0012) accompanying this module.

Here is an example on how to use `dpplot`

```
sysuse nlsw88, clear
dpplot wage, dist(exp)
gen artificial = -ln(uniform())
dpplot artificial, dist(exp)
```

For an alternative approach you can have a look at this article on ["Quantile-Quantile Plots without
Programming"](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=gr0027).

Comment: what about inverse Gaussian ? I dont see that distribution as being supported...any help ?

Comment: ok, got this: http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2006-12/msg00564.html ...